Kunen IV, lemma $2.12$
Clarification of notation: In Kunen, $\mathbf{ZF}^{-}$ are the axioms of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory without foundation.
On page $117$ in Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs" we are given the following lemma:
Lemma:$(\mathbf{ZF}^{-}$). The Axiom of Fundation is true in any $\mathbf{M} \subset \mathbf{WF}$.
Now, I believe I have followed pretty much everything in the chapter up to this point. But why does he write $\mathbf{ZF}^{-}$, does he mean we have to assume $\mathbf{ZF}$ - foundation for any $\mathbf{M} \subset \mathbf{WF}$ to model (if that is the correct word) foundation? If so, why?
Perhaps I have missed some subtlety leading up to this lemma, that motivates this assumption.
Comment: I belive I understood the (informal) proofs leading up to this statement, but perhaps we made assumptions that I missed in those proofs. Any clarification would be appreciated.
Comment 2: It feels weird to me that we need to assume some axioms, when we already know that $\mathbf{M}$ is a subset of the class of well-founded sets. Why can't one ``directly" prove this from inherent properties of $\mathbf{M}$, that $\mathbf{M}$ inherits from $\mathbf{WF}$?

He means we are assuming $\sf ZF^-$ holds in the universe. In other words, for any class $\bf M$ such that $\sf ZF^-\vdash \bf M\subseteq WF,$ we have $\sf ZF^-\vdash (\mbox{axiom of foundation})^{\bf M}$. No assumptions are being made about what axioms hold in $\bf M.$
edit
Reading more closely, maybe that wasn't the confusion and you're wondering why we need to assume axioms in the background at all? Consider that it takes a fair amount of set theoretical machinery to define $\bf WF$ in the first place, let alone to prove that the axiom of foundation holds there (which is most of the work in proving it for any subclass).

Hmmm, I think I am still confused as to exactly what "provable in $\sf ZF^{-}$" means.

Thanks, your updated answer clears up atleast some of my confusion =).
And yes, that is what I was suspecting (regarding your comment about $\mathbf{WF}$; we need atleast some "background" machinery of ZF).

@Ben123 Sorry, didn't see your comment before I edited. $(\mbox{axiom of foundation})^{\bf M}$ is a statement in the language of set theory. We just mean there's a proof of that statement from the axioms of $\sf ZF^-$.

I think this touches on something I see people use often; "external" and "internal" to a model. I have not really internalized or understood what is meant with those concepts. Also "in the metatheory" contra "..." (can't remember the other word).
Or, like,  "a model witnesses" some property P. Perhaps this will become clearer (god willing).

@Ben123 Formally speaking, it's all syntactical and there are no models involved here (at least not in the paradigm Kunen's operating in). The overall goal is to show that there is a class $\bf WF$ definable in $\sf ZF^-$ such that for each $\sf ZF$ axiom $\phi$, $\sf ZF^{-}\vdash \phi^{\bf WF}.$ Then any proof of inconsistency in $\sf ZF$ could be converted to one in $\sf ZF^-$  by relativizing every statement in it to $\bf WF.$ Thus we have $\sf Con(ZF^-)\to Con(ZF).$

@Ben123 Chapter IV discusses the metamathematical stuff in detail (and there's also quite a bit scattered throughout the rest of the text, and the appendices of I and IV).
